# Changing attr value with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to change out a src value of an Iframe when a link is clicked and change out the value with the href from it. When the button is clicked, I prevent the default action, and replace the src value with the url. The code works for values that are not urls, causing the iframe to display a page not found, but does not work when a valid url is provided. Here is the code for the pages in use.

This is the main script I have been using to run the site

```
$.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
    });  
$(document).ready(function(){  

$('.pageContent').load('home.php');

setInterval("changePage()",250); 

});
function changePage(hash)
{

   $('.youtubeLink').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var temp = $(this).attr("href");
    //alert (temp);
    $('#youtubePlayerFrame').attr('src', temp);

//when using var temp no action occurs
//when testing temp, it does hold the url, if i replace temp with a string such as   
//'asdasd' the script works correctly but replaces the frame with a 404 error
})

  $(window).hashchange( function(){

    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;
    hash = hash.replace('#','');
    if (hash =='')
  {
  $('.pageContent').load('home.php');

  }

}
else
{
$('.pageContent').load( hash + '.php');
hash = null;
}
})
}
```

This code is the main div that holds the youtube player

```
<?php

echo '

<div class="youtubePlayer" >
<iframe width="420" height="315" id = "youtubePlayerFrame"   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/j8Szl_JyCUQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-top:34px; margin-left:20px;"></iframe>
</div>

';

include 'sideDirectory.php';
include 'sideMenu.php';


?>
```

This last code is the php file for the directory with the links

```
<?php
echo'

<div class="sideDirectory">
 <table><tbody>
 ';
 $file = fopen("../data/recentlyAdded.txt","r");

 $linksFile = fopen("../data/links.txt","r");

 while($line =fgets($file))
{

  $url = fgets($linksFile);
//   echo '<tr><td>' .$url. '</td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td><a class="youtubeLink" href="'.$url.'">'.$line.'</a></td></tr>';     
}
fclose($file);
fclose($linksFile);
echo '
</tbody> </table>
</div>
';
?>
```

Comment: Holy crap, you're binding a new click event four times every second, how's that working out for you ?

Comment: WAAHHHH! It's an iframe. Might this have something to do with some same-origin-policy in your browser or something?

Comment: Why not just have your anchor tags *target* the iframe? `target="iframeid"`

Comment: Looking into the same-origin-policy

Comment: im trying to target the iframe too, doesn't seem to be working as of now

Answer (score 0):

Try it more like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });  
    $('.pageContent').load('home.php')
                     .on('click', '.youtubeLink', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#youtubePlayerFrame').prop('src', this.href);
                     });

    $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
        var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
        $('.pageContent').load( (hash.length ? hash : 'home') + '.php');
    });
});
```

Binding event handlers really has no place in an interval that runs four times a second, they only need to be bound once to work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out and cleaning up the code, still learning by trial and error. It still isn't correctly loading the frame though, just sits there. Here's the link if anyone wants to see for themselves http://musicsharing.co.nf/pages/home.html and then click the circle button in the header

Comment: And where is `.youtubelink` and `#youtubePlayerFrame`? These are elements created by you right, they're not on Youtube ?

Comment: No the links in that directory are under the class .youtubelink, and the frames id is #youtubePlayerFrame that I am trying to load the url into